# How do I decrease the count of an element in a multiset in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using a multi-set in c++, which I believe stores an element and the respective count of it when it is inserted.

Here, when I want to delete an element, I just want to decrease the count of that element in the set by 1 till it is greater than 0.

Example C++ code:

```
    multiset<int>mset;
    mset.insert(2);
    mset.insert(2);
    printf("%d ",mset.count(2)); //this returns 2
    // here I need an O(1) constant time function (in-built or whatever )
    // to decrease the count of 2 in the set without deleting it 
    // Remember constant time only

      -> Function and its specifications

    printf("%d ",mset.count(2)); // it should print 1 now .
```

Is there any way to achieve that or should i go by deleting that and inserting the element 2 by the required (count-1) times?

Comment: Have you considered using a `unordered_map<int, int> um;` so you could do `um[2] = 1;`?

Comment: O(1) ? I doubt that's possible. And what do you mean, "without deleting it" ? Either you have two `2`'s in your multiset, or you don't...

Comment: @nwp , Actually after certain number of insertions and deletions , i need to report the element with maximum frequency in less than O(n) => O(logN) where the set is only thing i found....

Comment: @Quentin , Suppose i have an array where i need to tell max repeated element with some queries having a range between the bounds of this array.. So im using Mo algorithm here . SO if i answerd query [1-5] ( i.e 1st to 5th element . So i go on adding them to set and report maximum for that range ) and later if i need to answer [2-4] , i need to decrease the count of 1 and 5th element in the set .... Hope i made it clear to you

Comment: And so if by chance any of the 1st and 5th element in repeated in 2,3,4 , then when i need to answer maximum count of an element in the set , i need to decrease the elements count but not the entire element till it completely gets deleted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... I am using a multi-set in c++, which stores an element and the respective count of it  ...

No you aren't. You're using a multi-set which stores *n* copies of a value which was inserted *n* times.

If you want to store something relating a value to a count, use an associative container like `std::map<int, int>`, and use `map[X]++` to increment the number of Xs.

> ... i need an O(1) constant time function ... to decrease the count ...

Both `map` and `set` have O(log N) complexity just to *find* the element you want to alter, so this is impossible with them. Use `std::unordered_map`/`set` to get O(1) complexity.

> ... I just want to decrease the count of that element in the set by 1 till it is >0

I'm not sure what that means.

- with a set:

  - to remove *all* copies of an element from the set, use `equal_range` to get a range (pair of iterators), and then erase that range
  - to remove all-but-one copies in a non-empty range, just increment the first iterator in the pair and check it's still not equal to the second iterator before erasing the new range.

  these both have an O(log N) lookup (`equal_range`) step followed by a linear-time erase step (although it's linear with the number of elements having the same key, not N).
- with a map:

  - to remove the count from a map, just erase the key
  - to set the count to one, just use `map[key]=1;`

  both of these have an O(log N) lookup followed by a constant-time erase
- with an unordered map ... for your purposes it's identical to the map above, except with O(1) complexity.

Here's a quick example using `unordered_map`:

```
template <typename Key>
class Counter {
    std::unordered_map<Key, unsigned> count_;
public:
    unsigned inc(Key k, unsigned delta = 1) {
        auto result = count_.emplace(k, delta);
        if (result.second) {
            return delta;
        } else {
            unsigned& current = result.first->second;
            current += delta;
            return current;
        }
    }
    unsigned dec(Key k, unsigned delta = 1) {
        auto iter = count_.find(k);
        if (iter == count_.end()) return 0;
        unsigned& current = iter->second;
        if (current > delta) {
            current -= delta;
            return current;
        }
        // else current <= delta means zero
        count_.erase(iter);
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned get(Key k) const {
        auto iter = count_.find(k);
        if (iter == count_.end()) return 0;
        return iter->second;
    }
};
```

and use it like so:

```
int main() {
    Counter<int> c;
    // test increment
    assert(c.inc(1) == 1);
    assert(c.inc(2) == 1);
    assert(c.inc(2) == 2);
    // test lookup
    assert(c.get(0) == 0);
    assert(c.get(1) == 1);
    // test simple decrement
    assert(c.get(2) == 2);
    assert(c.dec(2) == 1);
    assert(c.get(2) == 1);
    // test erase and underflow
    assert(c.dec(2) == 0);
    assert(c.dec(2) == 0);
    assert(c.dec(1, 42) == 0);
}
```

Comment: `map` and `set` complexity to find an element is O(log N)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I meant to say :) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the info . And i Want to report the element with maximum count value  . i.e which was inserted maximum times And i need to do  it in less than or equal to O(logN) . Is there any possibility while using unordered _map by the way .....

Comment: You can do that in linear time at best using the container, or constant time if you just track the current max frequency and most frequent value as you go inserting. Correcting that after decrement is linear again though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment . I GOT it useless